# When I try to mine ethereum I get JSON-RPC error

Tags: mining, json-rpc, cpp-ethereum, gpu, ethminer

I am new at ethereum mining and I am trying to solo mine. I already installed geth and now I am trying to mine. When I go to ethereum software folder and type ethminer -G, it gives me the following error:

miner  20:17:35.189|main  Getting work package...
  X  20:17:36.390|main  Failed to submit hashrate.
  X  20:17:36.393|main  Dynamic exception type: class jsonrpc::JsonRpcException
std::exception::what: Exception -32003 : Client connector error: libcurl error: 7 -> Could not connect to http://127.0.0.1:8545

JSON-RPC problem. Probably couldn't connect. Retrying in 1...

What can be the problem?

Comment: How does this involve C++?

Comment: Ethereum is somehow using it. Even folder is called cpp-ethereum. So I guess it may be the cause of problem.

Comment: That is not how the tags work.  If you have a problem with actual C++ code then you use the C++ tag.

Comment: how did you started miner? In ethereum you generally define the services that you want to enable for miner while starting the miner in cmd line args

Comment: @radbrawler I didn't pass any arguments, as the tutorial said, i just typed ethminer -G. any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you run any `geth` command? Can you give me the link of tutorial you used ?

Comment: @radbrawler https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/guides/how-to-mine-ethereum/

Comment: seems your blockchain is yet to sync with main network. Is your blockchain synchronised with network?

Comment: @radbrawler it totally is synchronised. It has imported every block and is most likely ready to mine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140098/discussion-between-radbrawler-and-georgedopeg).

Comment: Did you solve this one? I'm having the same.

Comment: Try running geth --rpc in a separate window.